# Which are some programming languagues "personalities"?

Tags: animation

This may be the weirdest question ever made here...

But its for a programming class animation project where we are learning about the differences about paradigms.

The project is based on the "Hi I'm a Mac, Hi I'm a PC" advertising, but instead of being about OS, we must show in an animation the differences between four different languages with four different paradigms...

My idea... romantic and artistic as i think i am... is that the 4 would compete for a girl to whom they want to declare their love by giving her a letter.

Chessy, right?

The "cool" part is that the girl looks like this [concept art](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/2522/img20130430024252.jpg) and the letter would just say: "Hello, World." :)

So...

if you still don't think this is the stupidest thing in the world, and this is allowed here, this is my question:

**

### Which are JAVA'S, C'S, VISUAL BASICS'S, RUBY'S or PHP'S  "personalities"?

**

For example:

- Java (object-oriented) - gives her lots of gifts
- Visual Basic (event-driven) - dates, events, parties

And that's it...

Do This languages would work? I'm still not sure how different they are?
Should i get other languages so it would be easier to understand the differences between paradigms? Any opinions about the animation? Should World stay single?

any help of ANY kind would be amazing, thanks :D

Comment: I think you mean `cheesy` where you have `chessy`.  And yes, very cheesy. Ruby, if I remember the song correctly, is a cheap tramp who takes herself out every night drinking and carrying on with men while her war-crippled husband sits at home singing dolefully.  I guess you could work some personality out of that.

Comment: I like your question :D but I don't think stackoverflow is the right place for it. Anyway C -> fast, light but ugly   Java -> there is a factory for it

Answer (score 1):

Here's some info which might help:

- VB is stodgy, corporate, square-headed & crufty -- like Dilbert.
- Ruby is like a web designer -- flashy & quick but probably crunky behind the scenes.
- Java is like an expensively-suited contractor, integrating to mainframes.
- C is like.. a hairy-bearded engineer, with a big wrench & some bare iron?
- PHP is like..  some Unixy guy, more a VI/ text processing guy rather than the C guy?

Fill in the ways they express these personalities, yourself.  Java guy can have a flash car & work on airline reservation systems (hence travel). Web designers are pretty easy to characterize. You do the rest.